# How to request instances managed by Dagger by only using the @Inject annotation in all classes?

Tags: javafx, dependency-injection, ejb, dagger, gluon

Hopefully you will know what I mean by the question, if I explain the context of what I want to do:
I am trying to use Dagger with the Gluon Ignite library in my JavaFX project.

My setup is a bit strange: 
I have a an EJB project containing several classes that should be shared between clients. It contains two classes annotated with @Stateless and @Singleton, so they are deployable as EJBs on an application server.
I want to use the classes of the EJB module from a standalone JavaFX application. So the JavaFX client should work without the EJBs deployed to an application server.

Therefor I told gradle to package the EJBs classes in the JavaFX application. The EJB module is also part of an EAR project that is created via gradle multi-project build to make it deployable. The build of the JavaFX is independent of the EAR module and the multi-project configuration.
Now I want to use Dagger (Gluon Ignite) to inject the services from the EJB module. If possible, I don't want to 'polute' the EJB classes with any dagger-specific code to still be able to deploy it as a standard EJB module. Also the EJBs should be able to request instances of each other. I can't believe it doesn't work since Dagger is based on the JSR-330 standard annotations.

I've got injection working only out of my Application class by adding

```
private final DIContext context = new DaggerContext(this, () -> Arrays.asList(new DaggerApplicationModule()));
@Inject
GlobalService globalService;
```

I wrote one dagger module that only contains the provider for a class that should be injected via an interface. For the other classes I added @Inject to their no-argument constructor. As far as I understand the method call `context.init();` (belonging to Gluon Ignite) in the start method of the application class causes the field injection to happen. 
In contrast to that I figured out that one way to resolve the dependencies in other classes than my Application class is by manually writing something like this:

```
ObjectGraph og = ObjectGraph.create(new DaggerApplicationModule());
globalService = og.get(GlobalService.class);
```

Otherwise, by annotating the fields with @Inject, they remain null. For me this looks like annoying boilerplate code that I would resent having in my EJB classes. Do I really have to write something similar manually? Maybe I'm getting the whole concept wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Dagger still requires you list the classes in the `Module` annotation. Here is the module definition from the Ignite Dagger example. Note the "injects" attribute:

```
@Module( library = true, injects = {DaggerApp.class,ViewController.class}, complete = false)
class DaggerModule  {

    @Provides
    public Service provideService() {
        return new Service();
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, for sure I did some trial and error with the injects attribute. In my configuration the only class required by the compiler is the application class. For my understanding it would make perfect sense to also tell Dagger about the ViewController class as it's an entry point of the ObjectGraph and is not created by Dagger itself, but unfortunately that doesn't make any difference.